# Javacc left recursion

Tags: javacc

I need to implement this grammar

```
       Exp ::= Exp op Exp
           ::= Exp [ Exp ]
           ::= Exp . length
           ::= Exp . id ( ExpList )
           ::= INTEGER LITERAL
           ::= true
           ::= false
           ::= id
           ::= this
           ::= new int [ Exp ]
           ::= new id ()
           ::= ! Exp
           ::= ( Exp )
```

and this is what I have done so far

```
void Exp() :
{}
{
  ExpOp()            
| "INTEGER" "LITERAL"
| < TRUE >
| < FALSE >
| < ID >
| < THIS >
| < NEW > < INT > < LBR > Exp() < RBR >
| < NEW > < ID > < LPAR > < RPAR >
}

void ExpOp():
{}
{
    Exp() (
            (< OP > Exp())
          | (< LBR > Exp() < RBR >)
          | (< DOT >   ( < LEN >
                       | (< ID > < LPAR > ExpList() < RPAR >) )))
}
```

but I don't know how to remove left recursion for function Exp.

I tried to add another function ExpOp but this didn't work

Comment: This sort of question has been asked and answered many times.  Left-recursion removal is a standard problem whose solution is covered in just about any book on parsing or on compiling, not to mention online resources such as Wikipedia.

If you are translating to an intermediate form such as an AST or a machine code, you need to worry about whether op is left- or right-associative. When there are multiple operators you need to also worry about precedence. 

Here is a link to an article I wrote that covers all these aspects: https://www.engr.mun.ca/~theo/Misc/exp_parsing.htm .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
void Exp() :
{}
{
    ExpOp() (
        < OP > Exp()
    | < LBR > Exp() < RBR >
    | < DOT > (
        < LEN >
        | < ID > < LPAR > ExpList() < RPAR >
        )
    )?
}

void ExpOp():
{}
{
    "INTEGER" "LITERAL"
    | < TRUE >
    | < FALSE >
    | < ID >
    | < THIS >
    | < NEW > (
        < INT > < LBR > Exp() < RBR >
        | < ID > < LPAR > < RPAR >
        )
}
```